# How to modify the size and positionning of an edge in a flow chart using LayeredGraphPlot command?

Tags: programming

**Hello,
I am trying to make the diagonal edge (\mu N) horizontal and short in the following code corresponding to a flow chart:**

```
vertices = vertices = {"S", "I", "D", "R"};
groups = {{"S"}, {"I"}, {"R", "D"}};
colors = Flatten@
   MapThread[Thread@*Rule, {groups, {White, Yellow, Red}}];
edges = {Style[Labeled["S" -> "I", \[Beta] "I"/\[Mu]  S/"N"], Red, 
    Thick], Style[Labeled["R" -> "S", Subscript[\[Gamma], r]], Brown, 
    Thick],
   Style[Labeled["I" -> "R", Subscript[\[Gamma], i]], Brown, Thick], 
   Style[Labeled["I" -> "S", \[Delta]], Brown, Thick]};
```

Then I added some invisible vertices to my flow chart as follows:

```
invisiblevertices = {"SS", "Rb", "Sb"};

newedges = {Style["S" -> "SS", Black, Thick], 
   Style["Sb" -> "S", Black, Thick], 
   Style["R" -> "Rb", Black, Thick], Style["I" -> "D", Black, Thick]};

newedgelabels = {Style[Subscript[\[Mu], s], Bold, Thick], 
   Style["\[Mu] N", Bold, Thick], 
   Style[Subscript[\[Mu], r], Bold, Thick], 
   Style[Subscript[\[Mu], i], Bold, Thick]};

edges2 = Join[edges, MapThread[Labeled, {newedges, newedgelabels}]];


options = {VertexLabels -> {_ -> Placed[Automatic, Center], 
     Alternatives @@ invisiblevertices -> None}, 
   VertexShapeFunction -> {"S" -> "Square", "R" -> "ConcaveHexagon", 
     "D" -> "ConcaveHexagon", 
     Alternatives @@ invisiblevertices -> None}, 
   VertexStyle -> colors, 
   VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#1, 0.2], 
       Text[#2, #1]} &), VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> 450, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[11, Background -> White]};

flow = LayeredGraphPlot[edges2, Bottom, options, 
  PlotStyle -> {"TemperatureMap", Bold}]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

#### 1.

You can use a custom `EdgeShapeFunction` for the edge `"Sb" -> "S"`:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[edges2, Bottom, options, 
 PlotStyle -> {"TemperatureMap", Bold}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction ->
   {("Sb" -> "S") -> (Arrow[{#[[2]] + {1, 0}, #[[2]]}, .15] &)}]
```

[image]

#### 2.

Use the option `VertexCoordinates` and set the coordinates of `"Sb"` as desired:

```
vCoords = AssociationThread[
  VertexList @ edges2, 
  GraphEmbedding[edges2, {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Bottom}]];

LayeredGraphPlot[edges2, options, 
 PlotStyle -> {"TemperatureMap", Bold}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {"Sb" -> vCoords["S"] + {1, 0}, v_ :> vCoords @ v}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Dear @kglr, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @RimADENANE, you are most welcome.